# What is a good convention for namespaces for non-member non-friend functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Based off [Scott Myers advice](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) on preferring non-member friend functions over member functions in most cases that they make sense - what are recommended conventions for setting out the namespaces to do this?

In particular, how do you avoid nesting everything into namespaces and ending up with less readable code. Such as:

```
namespace Vector
{  
   class Vector2 {...};
   bool IsUnitVector(const Vector2& vector);
}
```

Resulting in calls such as:

```
Vector::Vector2 position;
if (Vector::IsUnitVector(position)) {...}
```

Is the following acceptable for example:

```
class Vector2 {...};
namespace Vector2
{
   bool IsUnitVector(const Vector2& vector);
}
```

To allow calls that are more readable, and grouped more logically:

```
Vector2 position;
if (Vector2::IsUnitVector(position) {...}
```

Comment: Questions asking for broad recommendation of best practices are off-topic at Stack Overflow.  There is no single, objectively correct answer to this question.  It is all a matter of debate and opinion.  Case in point:  you assert that, "nesting everything in to namespaces" results in "less readable code," but I would assert that, if you have chosen your names wisely, the opposite is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group them in the same namespace, and rely on argument-dependent lookup:

```
Vector::Vector2 position;
if (IsUnitVector(position)) {...}   // Magically resolves to Vector::IsUnitVector
```

Defining a namespace with the same name as a class is confusing at best, and likely to lead to ambiguity errors.